# Convert String to appropriate DataType

Tags: java, string, date

I have a `String` that could be in many different `formats`. I need to be able to recognize the actual type of the value at `runtime` and then transform the value to that type.

For example. If I have a `String` `Fri Feb 08 07:30:00 GMT 2013` this is actually a `Date` and a the `String` should be transformed into a `date object` and returned as such.

My current solution to this problem is to 'try' to convert it to a data type, if the conversion succeeds then all is good, if the conversion fails then move on to the next conversion attempt. This works, but is ugly and un-maintainable and I'm sure a better solution already exists out there.

Thanks.

Comment: What are all possible data types that a String can be converted to?

Comment: How would you expect to distinguish between "0" meaning "Really, I want a string just containing 0" and "0" meaning "the integer 0" and "0" meaning "a double value 0" and "0" meaning "a decimal value 0"? It would be *much* better if you could try to keep appropriate type information alongside the value.

Comment: can you show some other example strings? are these strings the output of `toString()` method?

Comment: @anubhava boolean, date, strings and numeric values for the most part

Comment: @MeNoMore I don't think it is a duplicate - in this question, the type is String so you can't cast to another type.

Comment: @JonSkeet For the purposes of my system a value of "0" can and should always be represented as a numeric value.

Comment: Numbers should always be instances of BigDecimal

Answer (score 4):

You may use separate regular expression for each data type like this:

```
private final static Pattern DATE_PATTERN = 
    Pattern.compile (
        "(?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat) " + 
        "(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June?|July?|Aug|Sept?|Oct|Nov|Dec) " + 
        "\\d\\d \\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d \\S+ \\d\\d\\d\\d");

private final static Pattern DOUBLE_PATTERN = 
    Pattern.compile (
        "[\\+\\-]?\\d+\\.\\d+(?:[eE][\\+\\-]?\\d+)?");

private final static Pattern INTEGER_PATTERN = 
    Pattern.compile (
        "[\\+\\-]?\\d+");

public static Object stringToObject (String string)
{
    if (DATE_PATTERN.matcher (string).matches ())
        return stringToDate (string);
    else if (DOUBLE_PATTERN.matcher (string).matches ())
        return Double.valueOf (string);
    else if (INTEGER_PATTERN.matcher (string).matches ())
        return Integer.valueOf (string);
    else return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Fri Feb 08 07:30:00 GMT 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat FT = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date d;
    try {
        d = FT.parse(s);
        System.out.println(d);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expression :
You can write a pattern for each data type you have, then match that pattern with each actual string you can associate a conversion for each match.
Here is a simple example (in pseudo Java):

```
String name = "Mike"; // This is an English name
String nameRegEx ="[A-Z][a-z]+"; //this patterns matches an english name
Matcher nameMatcher = new Matcher(regEx);
if (match.matches(name)){// I use the matches() method to verify the format of the string
    Name nameObject = Converter.getNameObjectFromString(name);//I make the conversion
}
```

Checkout the java documentation for more details on matchers and regular expressions :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine, if the strings passed to you are out of your control. Just one more suggestion: You should apply every possible conversion and check for ambiguous strings. If multiple conversions succeed then the string is ambiguous and you should do some error handling, probably throwing an exception.